# How to send or get date value by ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I need to send a few values to PHP using AJAX. My code works great with input type "text" but "date" doesn't work :( maybe its becouse Im using "serialize()". I spend all day to fix this problem... Im wrealy dummy in JS and AJAX its somethink *** for me so if you know how to solve this bug I'll be very appreciate!

My code HTML/JS:

```
  <form method="post" action="javascript:send('SendData.php','myform','result');" id="myform">
        <input type="text" name="whois" value="5" /><br/>
        <input value='2004-02-12' type='date' name="Date"><br/>
        <input type="button" value="Send" onClick="send('SendData.php','myform','result');" />
        </form>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function send(url,form_id,result_div)
{
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "SendData.php",
            data: $("#"+form_id).serialize(),

            success: function(html) {
               $("#"+result_div).empty();
               $("#"+result_div).append(html);
            },
            error: function() {
               $("#"+result_div).empty();
               $("#"+result_div).append("ERROR!");
            }
     });

}
</script>
```

and PHP

```
<?php
    echo $_POST['whois'];  
    echo '<br>';
    echo $_POST['Date']; 
    ?>
```

Comment: `success` and `error` have been deprecated. You might want to consider using [deferred objects](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), e.g. `.done()` and `.fail()` respectively.

Comment: I had a similar issue. Turns out it's due to the jQuery version I used. When I use latest jQuery [CDN](https://code.jquery.com/), it works just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works for me... http://jsbin.com/finomificoyo/1/edit showing two POST with data

Comment: Yeah, it's not the code per se, but the version of jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is you ar using

```
data: $("#"+form_id).serialize(),
```

to get your "data" value. But you in your code I can not see where is your id?

```
<input value='2004-02-12' type='date' name="Date"><br/>
```

I thing jQuery is unable to find the object

```
$("#"+form_id)
```

Try this

```
<input id="dataVal" value='2004-02-12' type='date' name="Date"><br/>
```

And inside Ajax use

```
data:$("dataVal").val();
```

To perform a test only do that:

```
alert($("dataVal").val());
```

Comment: The forms id is `id="myform"`

Comment: I don't think there's anything wrong. `<input>` elements do not need an ID, and the serialize function works with the form. As far as I can see, the `<form>` does have an ID of `myform` so that shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: You could use serialize. It is an option. I frequently use ajax to send information. To do that I do not use serialize. I prefer to retrieve information from each field. If you do not use serialize, you can try retrieve information using '$("id_element").val();' I think it is not a problem from Ajax. If you perform a 'alert()' test you will see.

Answer (score 0):

`serialize()` function returned string for get but you need use  `serializeArray` for get all form data in array and send in backend if you use method get you can use  `serlialize` function, but you use method post,  for post use `serilaizeArray()` funtion

`jQuery('#myform').serializeArray()`

Comment: Please explain your answer a bit instead of just saying "try this".

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a few curly brackets, so the javascript probably wont actually compile.
The browsers javascript debugger should have been able to tell you this if you had looked.

I am not sure if you are using an old jquery library, but if you are using a fairly current version try this.

```
function send(url,form_id,result_div)
{
    $.ajax({ type: "POST", url: "SendData.php", data: $("#"+form_id).serialize()})
      .done( function(html) {
           $("#"+result_div).empty();
           $("#"+result_div).append(html);
      })
      .fail( function() {
           $("#"+result_div).empty();
           $("#"+result_div).append("ERROR!");
      });
}
</script>
```